# Erro construtor parametrizado c++

Tags: c++, construtor

O que acontece quando uma classe com construtor parametrizado é criada, sem construtor padrão, e o objeto desse tipo é chamado sem argumento no construtor em c++?
Acontece erro de compilação?execução? exceção ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em C++ quando declaras um constructor parametrizado, o compilador não irá gerar o constructor por defeito (constructor sem parâmetros).

Do standard 12.1/5:

```
A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly declared.
```

Podes fazer um pequeno teste:

```
class Teste {
public:
    Teste(int v) { valor = v; }   

private:
   int valor;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     Teste t;  //irá gerar erro de compilação  
     return 0;

}
```

Para completar, podes indicar ao compilador para gerar o constructor por defeito independentemente da existência de qualquer outro constructor da seguinte forma:

```
class Teste {
public:
    Teste() = default;
    Teste(int v) { valor = v; }   

private:
   int valor;

};
```

Comment: Obrigado! era isso mesmo que estava em dúvida, que tipo de erro acontecia.